# how i can search in database using jTextField

Tags: java, database, jtable, jtextfield

hi every one i have write program that connect to database i create jTextField and jTable my question is how i can use the jTextField to serch in database and view in jTable the code i try is below

try{

```
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PROCAT";
    String uName = "zain";
    String uPass = "zain";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uName, uPass);
  String sql = "Select * from ITEMB where ITEM '"+asdf.getText()+"'";
   stmt = con.createStatement();

rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

  while (rs.next()) {
    String pr = rs.getString("PRISE");
    String it= rs.getString("ITEMNAME");
    String itm = rs.getString("ITEM");
    String[] data = {pr, it, itm};
    tabMode.addRow(data);
    double price = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("prise"));
             totalpay = price + totalpay;
            ++rowCount;
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    //ignore
    }

    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(totalpay));






}
```

Comment: One question per thread. First of all the second question doesn't make any sense (to me at least) and secondly it gets confusing when you have comments/answer relating to two different questions in the same thread and thirdly how will you be able to accept an answer if it doesn't answer both questions?

Comment: thank bro i make it one question and also thank for your advice about using the exception but i am try to figure this and still not work after i add the equal

Answer (score 2):

Don't ignore the Exception. How to you expect to debug your SQL if you don't display error messages???

I would guess the problem is you are missing an "=" from your select statement (ie. "ITEM = asdf.getText()").

However, the better way to use SQL is to use a `PreparedStatement` so you don't have to worry about all the delimiters. So the SQL might be something like:

```
String sql = "Select * from ITEMB WHERE ITEM = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, asdf.getText() );
stmt.executeQuery();
stmt.close();
```

It is much easier to read an maintain.